# how to move focus to faulty field in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, semantic-ui

I am using sematic UI react
https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-subcomponent-id
.In my example there is form having two field.I also done required validation .When I click on `button` it show `red border` to field if it is empty.I want focus will move to first error field if there is an error in fields
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/8yyqvvvj18

```
validateForm = () => {
    const { subscriberFirstName, subscriberMiddleName } = this.state,
      obj = { ...this.state };
    /* Empty validation*/
    let formError = false;
    if (!subscriberFirstName) {
      obj.subscriberFirstNameError = true;
      obj.formErrorMessage = "mandatory";
      formError = true;
    } else {
      obj.subscriberFirstNameError = false;
    }
    if (!subscriberMiddleName) {
      obj.subscriberMiddleNameError = true;
      obj.formErrorMessage = "mandatory";
      formError = true;
    } else {
      obj.subscriberMiddleNameError = false;
    }

    if (formError) {
      this.setState(preState => ({
        ...preState,
        ...obj,
        formError: true
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(
        preState => ({
          ...preState,
          ...obj,
          formError: false,
          formErrorMessage: ""
        }),
        () => {
          //  this.saveForm(false);
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

I want focus will move to first error field,when user click button.

**If there is an error in form focus will move to first error field**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autofocus an input field in semantic-ui-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177857/how-to-autofocus-an-input-field-in-semantic-ui-react)

Comment: See the second part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49237639/1342257

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar I already see this example but they used `Input` component.I used `Form.Input`

Comment: I already tried this solution .https://codesandbox.io/s/z2o44m51z3

Comment: I already tried this solution in my codesandbox.it works with `Input` component not with `Form.Input` see my `test and test2` file

Comment: I see that you have a `focus()` function, but I don't see that you _call_ it from anywhere.

Comment: i take `a = [];` a array to store all input node . but in case of `Form.Input` it is giving null .

Comment: For `Form.Input`, you may need to reference the components `control` property to get the actual input node. E.g: `this.a[1].control.focus()`

Comment: Or store control: `this.a.push(c.control)`

Comment: yes till not I didn't call focus function .I am searching how I will work with `Form.Input`

Comment: (See above about the `control` variable`)

Comment: i will try and update you

Comment: not working ..https://codesandbox.io/s/z2o44m51z3 could you please update little bit code .because c is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189421/discussion-between-user944513-and-nikolas-stevenson-molnar).